# Single-threaded concurrency in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading, single-threaded

I am having difficulty understanding concurrency, single-threadedness and Python's threading. Is it possible to have single-threaded concurrency model in Python? How does such a model works

Comment: for single-threaded concurrency see **asyncio** https://realpython.com/async-io-python/ . Provides concurrency even on a single core microprocessor running Python on the bare metal with no OS to share tasks.

Comment: Yes, there are several concurrency packages in python (the builtin asyncio already noted) but many thinks such as the tkinter gui impolement event loops for single threaded concurrency. The basic idea is that code cooperatively returns to an event loop that lets other code run.